# Running Jobs in Parallel for same project and different branches

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

What do I need to change in order to run these jobs in parallel? 
There is one more runner available on the server, but it's not picking up the "pending" job until the "running" one is finished.

[image]

UPDATE

The jobs are picked up by different runners, but in a sequential mode. See ci-runner-1 and ci-runner-2. 
See screenshots

[image][image]

Comment: From posted screenshot we cannot be sure that jobs are beeing picked by different runners. Click on consecutive jobs details to check which runners they were running on and make sure they were not running on one and the same runner.

Comment: Yes, from the screenshot you cannot see the runners. I've updated the question. There are 2 runners and they run well but not in paralel.

Comment: Can you post your `config.toml` file where you have defined your runners? There's a setting at the top called `concurrent` that limits the global number of jobs that all runners on the same server can have. More info here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section

Comment: @MrBerta this is IT! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in config.toml (/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml in my case) I had:
concurrent = 1. 
Changed this to 0 or a value > 1, restart gitlab-runner and all good.

Reference:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section

Comment: It says `0 does not mean unlimited`, I wonder what does it mean then?